# repeating a regular expression pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to write a regex to match numbers in a given string, the below manages to retrieve the first number within the string, however it stops there, I would like it to match all numbers within the file, 
thanks in advance

regular expression :

```
([^\s+\w+\n\r]*(\d))+
```

string :

```
hi there this is 1
yes this is 2
```

actual match : 1
ideal match : 1,2

Comment: How are you using it? Please post relevant code. If you're interested of finding numbers in a given string, why not simply `re.findall(r'\d+', str)`?

Comment: I am simply running it in regex101.com

Comment: why not just `\d+`, `re.findall("\d+",string)`?

Comment: You should add `re.M` as the last parameter of `re.findall`.

Comment: it works in python i get that but it does not work on https://regex101.com/#python, really strange

Comment: BTW, `\s+` and `\w+` don't do what you think they do inside a `[]` set: the `\s` and `\w` are ok, but the `+` is interpreted literally, _not_ as a repetition meta-character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On site [regex101.com/#python](http://regex101.com/#python) type `g` in the right box near your expression. This box is called modifier. And as others mention in comments   use `re.findall(pattern, your_string)` in python. Notice also that you are actually looking for two substrings - you have two pairs of braces in your regexp.

Comment: i was going mad, i tried (\d+) initially and it did not work, adding g to the box to the right fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
"([\d]+)"g
```

Sample

```
test 13231 test 123123
123 asdfasdf 
1a2a3 a
```

will match

```
MATCH 1
1.  [5-10]  `13231`
MATCH 2
1.  [16-22] `123123`
MATCH 3
1.  [23-26] `123`
MATCH 4
1.  [37-38] `1`
MATCH 5
1.  [39-40] `2`
MATCH 6
1.  [41-42] `3`
```

and the explaination

```
"([\d]+)"g
    1st Capturing group ([\d]+)
        [\d]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \d match a digit [0-9]
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: That's **not** how you do greedy modifiers in Python `re` regexes. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Python doesn't have such syntax; there is no `g` flag. We have a [`findall()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead.

Comment: But why wrap the `\d` class in a `[...]` character class without adding anything to it?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters You're right. I could have skipped putting it into a character class. Bad habit of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `\d+` simply?

see [demo on regex101.com/#python](https://regex101.com/r/iD7zC9/1)